# SQL : Sum the data every 14 days in an entire year

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

> **EMP__ID**    | 
>    **Work_Date**   |   **Items_sold**
>
> ```
> 1         1/1/2010       10
>
> 2         1/1/2010        5
>
> 1         2/1/2010        7
>
> 1         3/1/2010       13
>
> 2         4/1/2010        6
> ```

I want to write a query that will **sum** the **"Items_Sold"** every **14 days** (fortnight)  for **entire year 2010**

to make it more clear , this query should return ( **26 rows** ) which is the number of **fortnights in a year** , in each row there will be the **total** Items_Sold that was captured in that particular **fortnight**

I'm using SQL Navigator ( oracle SQL )

thank you so much for your help

best wishes,,

Comment: When does the fortnight start?

Comment: Fortnight = every 14 days and start from  1/1/2010

Comment: What about when a fortnight overlaps with the next year?

Answer (score 2):

One approach might be to get the week from the date divide by 2, add .1 and then round it.  This will normalize the values from 52 to 26. The one problem is that there are 53 weeks, so you should test for when that occurs.

```
SELECT Round(Cast(To_char(work_date, 'WW') AS DEC(12, 2)) / 2 + .1) fortnight, 
       SUM(items_sold)  AS total_sold 
FROM   table1 
GROUP  BY Round(Cast(To_char(work_date, 'WW') AS DEC(12, 2)) / 2 + .1)
```

Note: I'm not near an Oracle box right now so I haven't tested this

Answer (score 1):

This query returns 26 rows that look like this.

```
FORT_START  FORT_END        JULIAN_DATE     SUM(ITEMS_SOLD)
--
01-JAN-10   14-JAN-10       14              15
15-JAN-10   28-JAN-10       28              -
29-JAN-10   11-FEB-10       42              7
12-FEB-10   25-FEB-10       56              -
26-FEB-10   11-MAR-10       70              13
12-MAR-10   25-MAR-10       84              -
26-MAR-10   08-APR-10       98              6
09-APR-10   22-APR-10       112             -
...
```

It creates a calendar--just a table of dates--for 2010. You can't really get all 26 rows without having 26 rows to join on.

```
with calendar as (
select cal_date
from
(
  select to_date('01 2010','MM YYYY')-1 + level as cal_date
  from dual
  where (to_date('01 2010','MM YYYY')-1+level) <= last_day(to_date('12 2010','MM YYYY'))
  connect by level<=365
)
order by cal_date
)
select cal_date - 13 as fort_start, cal_date as fort_end, 
       to_number(to_char(cal_date, 'DDD')) as julian_date, sum(items_sold)
from calendar
left join table1 on (work_date between cal_date - 13 and cal_date)
where (cal_date between date '2010-01-01' and date '2010-12-31'
       and mod(to_number(to_char(cal_date, 'DDD')), 14) = 0
      ) 
group by cal_date - 13, cal_date, to_number(to_char(cal_date, 'DDD'))
order by cal_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it

```
SELECT SUM(Items_sold) as num_sold
     , DATE_FORMAT(Emp_Date, '%Y') AS work_year
     , FLOOR((DATE_FORMAT(Work_Date, '%j') + 14) / 14) AS work_fortnight
  FROM thetable AS T 
 GROUP 
    BY DATE_FORMAT(Work_Date, '%Y'), FLOOR((DATE_FORMAT(Work_Date, '%j') + 14) / 14);
```

It's probably going to lop of new years eve, though. Guess you could easily account for that manually if necessary. I'll just assume this store isn't open then :)

Comment: looks suspiciously like MySQL syntax for an oracle problem

Answer (score 0):

This should get you exactly 26 rows, starting with January 1st with 14 day increments. Is that enough to get you started?

```
select to_date('01-01-2010', 'DD-MM-YYYY') + (level-1)*14
from dual
connect by level <= 26;
```